# new Control Center and widgets on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: 20.04, themes, extension, gnome-control-center, widgets

I am wondering if I may have something as the new Control Center and widgets on macOS Big Sur for Ubuntu 20.04?

[image]
<sup>**Control Center in macOS Big Sur**</sup>

Comment: If you make it, then, yes, you may.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-kde/. However, the control center does not look the same.